# Django global variable to store immutable object

Tags: django, concurrency, webhooks, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

I'm trying to set up `python-telegram-bot` library in webhook mode with Django. That should work as follows: on Django startup, I do some initial setting of `python-telegram-bot` and get a `dispatcher` object as a result. Django listens to `/telegram_hook` url and receives updates from Telegram servers. What I want to do next is to pass the updates to the `process_update` method of the `dispatcher` created on startup. It contains all the parsing logic and invokes callbacks specified during setup.

The problem is that the `dispatcher` object needs to be saved globally. I know that global states are **evil** but that's not really a global state because the `dispatcher` is immutable. However, I still don't know where to put it and how to ensure that it will be visible to all threads after setup phase is finished. So the question is how do I properly save the `dispatcher` after setup to invoke it from Django's `viewset`?

P.S. I know that I could use a built-in web server or use polling or whatever. However, I have reasons to use Django and I anyway would like to know how to deal with cases like that because it's not the only situation I can imagine when I need to store an immutable object created on startup globally.

Comment: Did my answer help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you need thread safe singleton like this one https://gist.github.com/werediver/4396488 or http://alacret.blogspot.ru/2015/04/python-thread-safe-singleton-pattern.html

```
import threading

# Based on tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance() approach.
# See https://github.com/facebook/tornado
class SingletonMixin(object):
    __singleton_lock = threading.Lock()
    __singleton_instance = None

    @classmethod
    def instance(cls):
        if not cls.__singleton_instance:
            with cls.__singleton_lock:
                if not cls.__singleton_instance:
                    cls.__singleton_instance = super(SingletonMixin, cls).__new__(cls)
        return cls.__singleton_instance
```